# Merge Google Sheets into a single Master Sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-merge, google-query-language

I am trying to merge and filter ranges (second their date) from different sheets into a master sheet. When using a single range it works but when adding a second range from a different sheet, like in this formula:

```
=QUERY({'Sheet1'!A3:I14 ; 'Sheet2'!A3:I14};"SELECT A, C, D, E, F, G, H, I WHERE (A >= date '" & text(today();"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND A <= date '" & text(today()+9;"yyyy-MM-dd") & "')"; false)
```

it gives the following error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: A.

What is the correct syntaxis to make the formula work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using A, B, C as field names use Col1, Col2, Col3

Comment: Now it works but it shows Empty Output, which it seems to be a common error.

Comment: Please add some sample data (usually also is a good idea to include a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view only)

Comment: It works now but found a not expected problem, made a question with example about it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64741932/add-column-with-sheet-name-of-origin-to-merged-sheet

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY({'Sheet1'!A3:I14; 'Sheet2'!A3:I14};
 "select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8
  where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY();   "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
    and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+9; "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"; 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. So when using more ranges with query is necessary to use Col1, Col 2,... instead?

Comment: @Preack always when you use "constructed" range with {} array brackets. if you use direct range you can use A,B,C... references