# Add column with sheet name of origin to merged sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language

Having this formula to merge and then filter by date, ranges from different sheets into a master sheet :

```
=QUERY({'Class 1'!A3:I14;'Class 2'!A3:I14}
,"SELECT Col1, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9 WHERE (Col1 >= date '" & TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND Col1 <= date '" & TEXT(TODAY()+9,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "')", FALSE)
```

The formula works like this: Grabs ranges from **Class 1** and **Class 2** sheets. Then it filters the results in the first column between today and 9 days from now. For each filtered result everything on the right from the third column till the ninth column is then displayed.

In the Master sheet I need to add a column containing the class (aka the name of the sheet of origin of each result) so is possible to understand from which class the students to be tested are from.

[Sheet of example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LAqsvFS_WRTUNaHA8NEBFZ0fcWU5LhJvxE8uEBrS_zc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: While you included a link to a spreadsheet it's better do include in the question body the desription of the data layout / structure as the spreadsheet might not be available later. Also you should include a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF` and `ARRAYFORMULA` to add the class name for the first sheet and apply the same patter for the second sheet.

A very rough way to apply the above:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({
'Class 1'!A3:I14,IF(N('Class 1'!A3:I14),"Class 1");
'Class 2'!A3:I14,IF(N('Class 2'!A3:I14),"Class 2")
},"SELECT Col1, Col10, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9 WHERE (Col1 >= date '" & TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-MM-dd") & "' AND Col1 <= date '" & TEXT(TODAY()+9,"yyyy-MM-dd") & "')", FALSE))
```

`N` returns a number otherwise retuns nothing. It works in the above formula because the first column contains dates which Google Sheets handle them as serial numbers.

Please note that the SELECT clause was also modified, it shows Col10 as the second column.

Comment: @Preack Only for this time, I inserted a [new sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LAqsvFS_WRTUNaHA8NEBFZ0fcWU5LhJvxE8uEBrS_zc/edit#gid=1704241101) and added the above formula

Comment: Thanks, one of the reasons I asked you to make a live example is because the formula keeps giving a Formula Parse error in my real sheet. No matter what I try the formula still doesn't work in the real sheet for some reason. I'll keep troubleshooting the problem, meanwhile...
Do you mind to explain why the Col10 is there?

Comment: @Preack The Col10 is there because the Class calculation is added after the original columns (they are 9)

Comment: By the way, the example spreadsheet is using United Kingdom as Locale. What locale is using your real spreadsheet?

Comment: @Preack Have you tried to copy the formula from the demo spreadsheet to the real spreadsheet

Comment: I checked, even if I change the Locale doesn't affect the formula.

The only thing that it worked in the end is to copy the whole sheet into the real spreadsheet, without this way of 'importing' the formula nothing else worked. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
 {'Class 1'!A3:A14\ 'Class 1'!X3:X14&"Class 1"\ 'Class 1'!C3:I14; 
  'Class 2'!A3:A14\ 'Class 2'!X3:X14&"Class 2"\ 'Class 2'!C3:I14};
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9
  where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY();   "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
    and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+9; "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"; 0))
```

where X column is empty